# Swift - Segue only after TouchID Authentication

Tags: segue

Code with change root view controller:

```
let contexta:LAContext = LAContext()

        if contexta.canEvaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthentication, error: nil){
            contexta.evaluatePolicy(LAPolicy.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, localizedReason: "Please use TouchID") { (good, error) in
                if good{


                    DispatchQueue.main.async{
                    self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)

                        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)


                        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate! as! AppDelegate

                        let initialViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "myTabbarControllerID")
                        appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
                        appDelegate.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
                    }
```

Code is working with an issue regarding the AppDelegate.

Comment: Could you show, for comparison, the passcode button code that actually works?

Comment: could you show the complete code for the "with segue" case ?

Comment: I have posted the the passcode button code, the segue is created in the Main.storyboard file. This is the only code I have for the segue case.

Comment: So you are saying `self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueBio", sender: nil)` in two different places _in the same view controller_ but only one of them performs the segue? That makes no sense.

Comment: Yes, that is what is happening. On touchID, it will show the viewcontroller just for a bit then it goes back to the login screen.

Comment: Here is a link to the error: https://youtu.be/qEyoa0RZhG4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it code in the AppDelegate that kept loading the login screen. Thank you for the help!

Comment: I have the same issue.. how did you solve this? what changed did you do in AppDelegate?

Answer (score 1):

Code with segue is working as expected.

Comment: The code also works for me as well, but only for the 'passcode' button,

Comment: This is the error I am having with TouchID/FaceID: youtu.be/qEyoa0RZhG4

Comment: Can you please make sure that you have added: "Privacy - Face ID Usage Description" in Info.plist and have given permission. I have used the same code as yours. It seems correct only. Can you please confirm that you didn't perform any unwind segue from the second view controller.